# Change path of compiled files in the asdf?

Tags: common-lisp, asdf

How do I change the path that .fas files are placed in? By lisp code and not configuration file.

I am doing like this:

```
(asdf:disable-output-translations)
(push *default-pathname-defaults* asdf:*central-registry*)
(setq asdf:*central-registry*
      (append asdf:*central-registry*
             (directory (merge-pathnames
                         (make-pathname :directory '(:relative :wild))
                         *default-pathname-defaults*))))
```

With ECL, it generates the .fas and .o files in the source code directory being compiled, but I don't want it to be in the project directory, which is on a path that I go through, to better organize myself here.

Something like:

```
(asdf:set-path-compiled-files "/home/noloop/lisp-armv7a-libs/builds")
```

Answer (score 1):

`asdf:*central-registry*` is for the location of SOURCE, there isn't a single location for compiled results because asdf2 explicitly handles you using multiple implementations, which have incompatible fasl formats (this is a point of improvement in asdf2 vs the previous state of affairs).

According to [1] `(asdf:initialize-output-translations list)` can be used to set the translation programmatically, and `(asdf:ensure-output-translations)` can be used to see the current value

As mentioned in the DSL, you *must* include *one and only one* of `:inherit-configuration` *or* `:ignore-inherited-configuration`.

It's not clear if you also need to set one of `:enable-user-cache` or `:disable-cache` but choosing one seems sensible.

As stated in [2] the order matters.

On my machine, with sbcl:

```
cl-user> (asdf::initialize-output-translations '(:output-translations (t #p"/tmp/asdf/") :disable-cache :ignore-inherited-configuration))
```

Gives:

```
((#P"/home/peter/Programming/unix-built/sbcl/lib/sbcl/**/*.*" T)
 (#P"/tmp/asdf/" T) (T #P"/tmp/asdf/") (T T)
 (#P"/home/peter/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-2.0.0.104-b5a4454ca-linux-x64/**/*.*"
  T)
 (T
  #P"/home/peter/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-2.0.0.104-b5a4454ca-linux-x64/**/*.*"))
```

And with that I see FASLs in /tmp/asdf when I try and load a system.

1: http://soc.if.usp.br/manual/cl-asdf/asdf/Controlling-where-ASDF-saves-compiled-files.html#Controlling-where-ASDF-saves-compiled-files

2: https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/asdf/asdf/issues/22

Comment: I already read this, but doesn't see one example, and I don't know how to make it works.

Comment: I'm currently using `find $(SYSTEM_DIRS) -type f \( -name \*.fas -o -name \*.o \) -exec mv {} $(BUILD_DIR) ';'` but I prefer make it in the lisp.

Comment: I tried `(asdf:initialize-output-translations '(:output-translations `(#P"/home/noloop/lisp-armv7a-libs/builds")))` and doesn't work. I get: **Condition of type: INVALID-OUTPUT-TRANSLATION**. I also tried many ways of write this, and doesn't work too.

Comment: I tried `(asdf::initialize-output-translations '(:output-translations :disable-cache :ignore-inherited-configuration (t #p"/home/noloop/lisp-armv7a-libs/builds/")))` and doesn't work. It's saved in the source directory like as whether called  `(asdf:disable-output-translations)`.